# How do I send inputted email to built-in "reset password" view from custom template?

Tags: django, reset-password

I have a template with a custom "forgot password, please reset" form.

```
<form name="forgotPWForm" method="post">
    <input
        type="email"
        ng-model="forgotPW.email">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

That form is part of a template called `login.html`, which also has a login form. I want the user to type their email into the `input`, hit "Submit," and for the form to send the email to Django's `reset_password` view. But as I understand it, that view is limited to a certain template. How do I set up my "forgot pass" form to do what I described?

Comment: Are you trying to change the layout of the django administration change password page ?

Comment: @Lev No, I just want to send the inputted email to Django and have Django send a password-reset link to that email for the username associated with that email.